# Issue With App In The Software Center

Tags: 13.04, software-center, application-development

Hey I got my app published in the software center, (Yay!) but now I have a different. problem. When you go to download my app it says its free but but the button says buy where it normally says install. So it makes installing my app tedious and annoying. Can I get some help fixing that? My app is called Linux Disk Cleaner if you need to see my problem.

Thanks,
Brooks Rady

Answer (score 0):

Ive had same problem (the app was free but it told me to pay for it via something). The only solution for me was to go to app website and download & install the package manually (sudo dpkg -i xxx.deb).

Comment: Is there a way to contact somebody to fix it?